# Why "broadcast state" can store the dynamic rules however broadcast() operator cannot?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I got confused for the difference between  "broadcast state" and broadcast() operator, and finally I got the help from a Flink expert in the following thread.

[What does it mean that "broadcast state" unblocks the implementation of the “dynamic patterns” feature for Flink’s CEP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542294/what-does-it-mean-that-broadcast-state-unblocks-the-implementation-of-the-dyn/50542707)

In the end it seems got the conclusion that  "broadcast state" can store the dynamic rules in the keyed stream by RichCoFlatMap , however broadcast()  operator cannot, so may I know how "broadcast state" store the dynamic rules by RichCoFlatMap  and why broadcast()  operator cannot store the dynamic rules by RichCoFlatMap? May I got am example for explaining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are completely two different concepts. Moreover the `broadcast()` is kind of a prerequisite for `BroadcastState`.

`broadcast()` specifies partitioning of data, that says that each element of the stream should be broadcasted to each parallel downstream operator.

`BroadcastState` is a state of operator that first of all allows to be read-write from a broadcasted stream and read from non-broadcasted one. Before that there was no way to join such two streams. Moreover this state will ensure that after restore each instance of the state across all parallel instances will be the same.

For more information on the `BroadcastState` have look into [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html) docs.

Comment: "Before that there was no way to join such two streams" ,how about  using the broadcast() operator with CoFlatMapFunction and CheckpointedFunction? so broadcast() make sure "each element of the stream should be broadcasted to each parallel downstream operator" ,and  CheckpointedFunction  make sure the state would be fault tolerant, and can be rescaled . This would be achieve the same effect like "broadcast state"?

Comment: Yes, you could implement it that way, and it is pretty much how the BroadcastState is implemented. Moreover one crucial additional feature that BroadcastState introduced is the possibility to iterate over all keys, which is also crucial in "controlstream" use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

They are different concepts, BroadcastState is a storage concept, and Broadcast () is an operation whose purpose is to build BroadcastStream for you.